# check if money is in .99 cents increments

Tags: php

On some sites you can sell your item in .99 cents increments. I'm trying to validate if money is entered that way. Example:

- 0.00
- 0.99
- 1.99
- 2.99
- 3.99

Etc.  All ending in .99 cents unless free. So if someone entered `1.79` it would fail the check.

I was thinking Maybe substring/text hacks or division. Just kinda wondering how something like this could be done the best way for inputting. Like if someone wanted this pricing structure on their own site. Not asking for the full thing. Just need some pointers.

I'm thing so far:

```
<?php
function is99($money)
{
    if (!valid money)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (ends in 00)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ????
    }
}

if (is99($_post['price']))
{
    //allowed
}
else
{
    die('Price isn\'t in 99 cents increments. Please check the example.');
}
?>
```

Comment: You want to only allow user input that ends in `.99` or `.00`? Or you want to test another site for allowing `.99`? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Just added some more details. To explain better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `$_POST` you're dealing with strings. So you could validate the string, e.g. by comparing it against a simple pattern with string functions or a regular expression:

```
/^\d+.99$/
```

I only write that here, because [the mathematically fitting looking solution given above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953862/367456) does not show the whole picture because of [floating point precision<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). It will fail for an entered value like `2.99`. A slightly better version rounds the leftover as well:

```
/**
 * @param string $value
 * @return bool
 */
function is99($value)
{
    $leftover = round($value)-$value;
    return 0.01 == round($leftover, 2);
}
```

Doing it string-wise in the first place would not run into these kind of problems anyway.

However I wonder why you make it so hard to enter the data. If it needs to end with `.99` why don't you just create a fitting input? Like

```
Amount [____].99
```

The user can enter any positive integer number so you only need to check that. It's much more failsafe as the user can not enter so many wrong numbers. And the validation on the server-side is easier, too.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you:

```
if (round($amount) - $amount == 0.01){
     // do your thing here
}
```

Comment: That looks simple and makes sence. Maybe I was over thinking it.

Comment: This is really a bad answer (and the comments so far, too). First of all PHP has no problem to use `round` on strings (No need for `floatval` as ComFreek suggested), it will cast the value to `float`. Second this still does not work because of floating point precision issues. E.g. `round('2.99') - '2.99'` is `0.0099999999999998` and not `0.01`.

Comment: @hakre sorry to break it down for you, but considering the fact I have used this many times, it does work. About the string, yes indeed. Was confused with other languages.